# Java regex except combination of symbols

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find substing contains any character, but not include combination "[%"

As examples:

```
Input: atrololo[%trololo
Output: atrololo

Input: tro[tro%tro[%trololo
Output: tro[tro%tro
```

I already wrote regex, take any symbol except [ or %:

```
[A-Za-z-0-9\s!-$-&/:-@\\-`\{-~]*
```

I must put in the end of my expression something like `[^("[%")]`, but i can't solve how it should input.

You may check my regular in

https://www.regex101.com/

Put as test string this:

```
sdfasdsdfasa#@!55@321!2h/ хf[[[[[sds d
asgfdgsdf[[[%for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){}%]
[% fo%][%r(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ %]*[%}%]
[%for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){%][%=i%][%}%]
[%@n%]<[%@ n + m %]*[%@%]>[%@%]
%?s.equals(""TEST"")%]TRUE[%@3%]![%@%][%?%]
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead based regex like below to get the part before the `[%`

```
^(?:(?!\[%).)*
```

`(?:(?!\[%).)*` matches any character but not of `[%` zero or more times.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/wP7pR2/1)

```
String s = "tro[tro%tro[%trololo";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?!\\[%).)*");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());  // output : tro[tro%tro
}
```

**OR**

A lookahead based regex,

```
^.*?(?=\[%)
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/wP7pR2/2)

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.*?(?=\\[%)");
```

**OR**

You could split the input string based on the regex `\[%` and get the parts you want.

```
String s = "tro[tro%tro[%trololo";
String[] part = s.split("\\[%");
System.out.println(part[0]);  // output : tro[tro%tro
```

Comment: You a genius! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using your input/output pairs as the spec:

```
String input; // the starting string
String output = input.replaceAll("\\[%.*", "");
```

Comment: It's look like solution, but i can't able rebuild input stream.

Comment: What do you mean? "input" is a line as a String, not an input stream.